# Mirroring a Gitlab or Github repo to a selfhosted Gitea server

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitea

Good day all.

I am trying to mirror Git repositories, in full, for various OpenSource Projects that I am forking for my clients, in order to customizations.

These are the steps I am following:

```
$ git clone --mirror https://github.com/pathto/project.git
$ cd project.git
$ git remote set-url --push origin git@git.localserver.net:pathto/project
$ git push --mirror
```

And that last step I get a ! [remote rejected] on everything. (pre-receive hook declined)

I have setup the repository on Gitea and I have a SSH key installed. Everything uploads but then errors spits out for everything after the upload is complete.

My final step is to have a daily cron that does a fetch from github/gitlab and then a push to the local server.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out by Reading the Gitea manual.

Gitea has built-in repository mirroring, in both the push and the pull directions. Inside the organization, instead of creating a repository, create a migration and just follow the wizard.

It does everything for you.